# TKinter return file type from save dialogue?

Tags: python, tkinter

Using TKinter is there a way to know what file type was chosen in a `asksaveasfilename` or a `askopenfilename`? I would like to perform a different operation according to the file type that was selected.

Here is my solution, but its has shortcomings:

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

file_path = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Image file", '*.jpg'),
                                         ("Text file", '*.txt')))
if file_path:
    if Path(file_path).suffix == '.jpg':
        print("Image")
    elif Path(file_path).suffix == '.txt':
        print("Text")
    else:
        showerror("Save", "Unknown extension '{}'.".format(Path(file_path).suffix))
```

Comment: are you asking about the mimetypes library?

Comment: Why do you need to know which file type was selected? The function returns a file path with the correct file extension. Isn't that enough?

Comment: What shortcomings are you referring to?

Comment: @BryanOakley, There are edge cases that the solution I implemented above can not handle. For example if the user selects the `.txt` option and saves it as "document.temp", tkinter does not return this as "document.temp.txt", so I can not process it. It would be far better to have a function that returns a discreet file type index, rather than trying to assume it from context.

Comment: Selecting `.txt` merely filters the list. There's no way to know what the user chose in that case. The only thing you can get from the dialog is the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using TKinter is there a way to know what file type was chosen in a asksaveasfilename or a askopenfilename

No, there is not. The dialog has no type information to share. The file types that you specify are merely a filter for the user, which the user is free to use or ignore. The only information you can get from the dialog is whether the user picked a file or not, and the path of the file they picked. There is no other information you can get from the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

def savetext():
files=[('Text Document', '*.txt')]
file = asksaveasfile(title='Save as Text',initialdir='patha',filetype= files, defaultextension = files)
print(file.name)
#file.name is the path of the location chosen

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I know that this question is a long time ago but this answer, in case, for future generation, I found this:

```
from pathlib import Path 
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename 
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
    
file_type=(("Image file", '.jpg'), ("Text file", '.txt'))
file_path=asksaveasfilename(filetype=file_type, defaultextension=file_type)
print(Path(file_path).suffix)
```

I get the file type based on which `file_type` I chose.

[my python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEJ8C.png)

[File dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D3vE.png)

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB9ey.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiIwN.png)

Comment: This solution (using pathlib to extract the file suffix) is already in the question. This does not answer the question, you've just provided a slightly different workaround.